# Interactive plotting using pyvista and spyder

Tags: python, plot, spyder, point-clouds, pyvista

I have installed pyvista and its dependencies via `conda install -c conda-forge pyvista` in the ipython console in Spyder and after a bit of messing around it seems to work (I found that JsonCpp had to be installed manually from the console to access VTK).

I have started working through some tutorials (see below) but there is a problem with interactive plotting. When I try to render the point cloud object using `point_cloud.plot(eye_dome_lighting=True)`, it creates a bitmap of the scene in the console (using the default camera view judging by the tutorial) rather than an interactive plot in a new window ([console plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXY6i.png)). This is the default behavior I have in Spyder when using Matplotlib / PIL for plotting. Does anyone have a workaround? I am keen to use Spyder as my IDE for its Matlab-like features (my primary language). If Spyder-pyvista is a dead end perhaps someone could suggest a more compatible IDE with similar features to Spyder.

https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/create-point-cloud.html#sphx-glr-examples-00-load-create-point-cloud-py

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how spyder's ipython integration works _and_ I'm not familiar with the jupyter side either, so I don't know if these will help, but [there's a doc section](https://docs.pyvista.org/plotting/notebook_plotting/index.html) about plotting in notebooks.

Comment: Thanks for the link Andras - however, I am not sure this is going to help with Spyder (there is no notebook support in Spyder as far as I know)

Comment: PyVista developer here.  Can you try plotting using `notebook=False` and let me know here if it works?  We should consider having that as the default behavior on Spyder...

Comment: Thanks Alex: this fixed it. I you can place this as an answer I will accept.